# Sanitize raw SQL with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get the following request sanitized to send to a MySQL server:

```
  INSERT INTO `table`
  SELECT NULL, t.`id`, ?, ?
  FROM `table` AS t
  WHERE t.`some_field` = ?
```

The tricky part is that that request is to be executed in a class that **is not** my model class. It looks like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_method
    Service.new(self).run
  end
end

class Service
  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def run
    # Here is the request
  end
end
```

I've seen a lot of people using `Model#sanitize_sql`, but this is a protected method, which is unusable in my context.

Any idea?

**EDIT**:

It has been suggested that my question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402835/how-to-sanitize-raw-sql-in-rails-4). I've seen this question before posting, but the answers provided there aren't relevant in my case: I don't want to use [`quote`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/quote_value) because most of my fields are going to be numeric values. The other answer suggests not using raw SQL, but, as stated in the comments, I don't think ActiveRecord is capable of generating an [`INSERT...SELECT` query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html). ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768506/can-i-perform-a-insert-select-operation-with-the-rails-api/4877953) seems to confirm it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sanitize sql fragment in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009023/how-to-sanitize-sql-fragment-in-rails)

Comment: How does `run` actually look like when it generates that SQL query? Why can't you generate the query in the Model itself with standard Rails methods?

Comment: @Зелёный, I've seen this question, it doesn't address my problem.

Comment: @spickermann, I'm not using Rails, and I have to export higher order logic outside of the model itself. As far as OOP is concerned, the Model has nothing to do with the algorithm `run` represents. Also, I don't think ActiveRecord is capable of generating an `INSERT...SELECT` query, which is why I resort to raw SQL here.

Comment: I found [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-to_sql), which may well be what I'm looking for, but I can't get it right, and the documentation isn't really helping either.